# Why does `str_extract_all` return NA for non-matches?

Tags: r, match, stringr

I have a very large dataset containing more than half a million utterances from conversation. I'd like to extract those words that **contain** the string `well`, such as `jewellery` or `dwelling` but not the word `well` itself. I'm using `str_extract_all`:

```
library(stringr)
unlist(str_extract_all(X, "\\b\\w+well\\w+\\b"))
```

The extraction does work but it also returns `NA` for each utterance where the pattern does *not* match. I get an output like this:

```
...
[568] NA          NA          NA          NA          "jewellery" NA          NA          NA          NA 
....
```

I can prevent getting `NA`s by subsetting the data on the pattern to be extracted:

```
unlist(str_extract_all(X[grepl("\\b\\w+well\\w+\\b", X)], "\\b\\w+well\\w+\\b"))
```

But doing so is unwieldy and, curiously, the extraction using `str_extract_all` works just fine in another *smaller* dataset here called `sample`, structured just like the big dataset:

```
sample <- c("well you can use that for any argument then",
            "he said well what have , what am i gon na get him poor feller !",
            "that 's what he was doing , hoping i was asleep .",
            "was hoping this afternoon to get the curtain rail .",
            "you do tend to skip by if there 's another one that you think oh well",
            "but the swellings gone down mostly i 've got gloves","is n't he ? sort of jewellery you see .",
            "since you done it we 've been looking in jewellers ' shops")

unlist(str_extract_all(sample, "\\b\\w+well\\w+\\b"))
[1] "swellings" "jewellery" "jewellers"
```

Why does it work here all of a sudden and, more importanly, how can I tweak the extraction of the target words from the large dataset so that only raw matches are listed but not `NA`?

Comment: Do you have `NA` in `X`? `sample[1] <- NA` will give `NA` with your *smaller* dataset. `unlist(str_extract_all(X[!is.na(X)], "\\b\\w+well\\w+\\b"))` might help.

Comment: Maybe you want `\\b\\w*well\\w+\\b|\\b\\w+well\\w*\\b` instead of `\\b\\w+well\\w+\\b`.

Comment: @GKi Thanks both for the better pattern as well as the tip re NA: indeed, if I remove NAs from the dataset, the extraction works as intended. Do post as an answer so I can accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you have `NA` in the vector `stringr::str_extract_all` will return `NA`:

```
sample[1] <- NA
unlist(stringr::str_extract_all(sample, "\\b\\w+well\\w+\\b"))
#[1] NA          "swellings" "jewellery" "jewellers"
```

To get rid of `NA` you can remove `NA` using `is.na` like:

```
unlist(stringr::str_extract_all(sample[!is.na(sample)], "\\b\\w+well\\w+\\b"))
#[1] "swellings" "jewellery" "jewellers"
```

or you use `gregexpr` and `regmatches` from *base*:

```
unlist(regmatches(sample, gregexpr("\\b\\w+well\\w+\\b", sample)))
#[1] "swellings" "jewellery" "jewellers"
```